# CSS Layout Design - Multi Columns inside Multi Columns

Tags: css

Incredibly new to CSS, I have done some very basic stuff over the years but I am trying to find a solution to a design I would like to create for my Drupal product page.  I have tried searching but it's like since I am self-taught I have no idea what terms I should be searching for.

Here is the layout I am looking to design (attached).

So I want basically a 2 column layout with a 3 column header that is located in the main section.  Should/Can I do this with grids?  I am not too terrible sure what I should be searching for to understand how to make this happen.  My only concern with a grid is that I can't have the sidebar contained to a single row height.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much![image: Planned Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for a grid-based system, I would highly recommend taking a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for implementing your desired layout. Take a look at the link and it will explain how exactly to achieve your layout specified above.

Comment: I will take a look but like I mentioned above - I don't know if I need a grid layout to accomplish this.  That was part of my question, should I? :)

Comment: Yes, I think that you definitely should implement this design using a grid system, in particular a responsive grid system. The reason why I suggested Bootstrap is because it abstracts a lot of the stuff that a person would need to worry about trying to set this up themselves away using a set of easy-to-use and well documented classes and HTML structures. Since you mentioned that you are very new to CSS, I thought that this would be a great way for you to learn about CSS design concepts as well as learn how to use a widely used grid system framework.